# How to Change Image Date in Application in android?

Tags: android

How to change the written images by day and date so that the image changes to the day after the date on which

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you wish to modify the date of an image? When it was last modified?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, this method might help you:

```
try
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    File file = new File("path_to_your_file");

   //set this date 
   String the_date_you_want_to_set = "16/10/2015";

   Date modifiedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(the_date_you_want_to_set= );
   file.setLastModified(modifiedDate.getTime());
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help if you're talking about JPEG photos. This changes the metadata of the image:

```
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import java.util.*;

....

ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
String date = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME); //or TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED or TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP or TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP
if(date == null) //do something;
```

Do whatever processing is necessary to determine what that date is. Then, maintaining the format of the string, change it so it reflects the next day. One way to increment the day is

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);
c.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
int updatedYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int updatedMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int updatedDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Then update the file with:

```
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, updatedDate); //use whichever TAG_ you used in the first part
exif.saveAttributes();
```